# Legend text not printing with Mapfish print

Tags: geoserver, mapfish, geonode, config.yaml

I am using GeoNode 1.6.11 and GeoServer 2.7.4. I am configuring Mapfish Print's config.yaml file to show the legend, but it is not working properly. I have the icons showing up on the PDFs, but the layer text is not appearing. This is my legend entry in the config.yaml:

```
    - !legends
      backgroundColor: #0033cc
      horizontalAlignment: left
      borders: false
      layerFont: Helvetica
      layerFontSize: 10
      layerSpace: 5
      maxIconWidth: 50
      maxIconHeight: 50
      classFont: Helvetica
      classFontSize: 20
      classSpace: 5
      classIndentation: 20
      fontEncoding: Cp1250
```

The result is a legend with all icons, but no text labels. How can I get the legend text to appear on the PDF output? Is this a geoserver/style issue or a print module/config.yaml issue?

UPDATE: when a layer only had 1 category, the layer text does not appear on the legend. When the layer has multiple categories, it does appear, but it is very tiny (with the settings above). Note that the styling was done within GeoNode.

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve it? I know that if you increase maxIconWidth and maxIconHeight the legend text of multi category layers will increase, but I don't know how to display legends in single category layers.